# Concatenar texto com variável char no printf()

Tags: c, string, printf

Preciso concatenar o nome da pessoa (variável) com um texto. Seguindo a lógica, ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void){
    char nome[6];
    printf("Ola! Insira seu nome, por fovor: \n");
    scanf("%c", &nome);
    printf("Seja bem vindo, \n", nome);
    return 0;
}
```

Mas não da certo. Preciso disso da maneira mais simples possível.

Comment: Um jeito simples de concatenar Char em C++ https://youtu.be/ZkYhmHD7XRo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Há 3 problemas no código:

1. o formato para *string* no `scanf()` é `%s` (melhor usar um limitador da quantidade de caracteres que pode entrar)
2. como o *array* já é uma referência para um objeto basta passar a variável, não pode pegar o endereço de algo que já é um endereço
3. o `printf()` está sem o *placeholder* para acomodar o nome

Então ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char nome[6];
    printf("Ola! Insira seu nome, por fovor: \n");
    scanf("%5s", nome);
    printf("Seja bem vindo, %s\n", nome);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/st73Zc). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dzebwujk-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Console/Printf2.c).

[Documentação da formatação do `printf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: English:  Not quite correct.  If the user enters more than 5 characters, the input buffer `nome[]` will be overflowed.  resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.  Suggest:`scanf("%5s", nome);`

Comment: Melhorei, mas se for para fazer correto mesmo, melhor nem usar `scanf()`.

Answer (score 3):

Existem vários métodos para concatenar strings em C, você pode usar o `sprinf`, ou o `strcat`.

O `sprintf`, funciona igual ao `printf`, a diferença é o parâmetro referente a string que vc irá inserir o valor.

> Pode concatenar números e pontos flutuantes usando o `sscanf`.

strcat:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char str1[50];
    char str2[50];
    char cat[100];

    strcpy(str1,"texto da string1"); // insere o texto em str
    strcpy(str2," | nova parte do texto");

    bzero(cat, 100); // limpa a variavel cat

    strcat(cat, str1); // concatena valores em cat
    strcat(cat, str2);

    puts(cat);
}
```

sprintf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    char str1[50];
    char str2[50];
    char cat[100];

    sprintf(str1,"Primeira parte");
    sprintf(str2,"Segunda parte");
    sprintf(cat,"%s - %s",str1, str2);

    puts(cat);
}
```